# IntegrationTest controllers with .net core 2.0 on web api

Tags: c#, integration-testing, asp.net-core-2.0

I've just created an empty web api project with .net core 2.0.
I have a default controller and I want now create an integration test.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

The goal is self host in the integration then enter url api/values and check the return.

NB: I only use wep api 2 and owin, and it was quite easy to do this. But the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/owin says that .net core application should not use owin, so what should we use and how to it?

Comment: why don't you call the methods from your controller?

Comment: because if I instanciate the controler and call the Get() directly it does not test the route and the fact that is call on a Http GET. That would be more a unit test.

Comment: This link could help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks but not really as it's for Web API 2 and it's UnitTesting. I'm interested by Integration Tests for .net core 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the official documentation for integration testing with ASP.NET Core 2.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing

The main idea is to create a `TestServer` instance with a `WebHostBuilder` configured with your `Startup` class. You can then get a `HttpClient` instance from the `TestServer` to call your self-hosted api